# MSI Installer error 2203; how to force permissions on installer directory?

Tags: model-view-controller, windows-7, permissions, windows-installer, asp.net-mvc-3

*[Cross-Posted on SuperUser.com as well because the question relates to permissions. Feel free to let me know where it best belongs.]*

Hi all,

I'll try to bullet-point to keep it short:

#### Background / Issue

- Trying to install ASP.NET MVC 3 RC on my Windows 7 machine.
- Uninstalled other versions of MVC (2 and 3 Beta 1).
- Ran the installer -- got a generic error, 2203.
- Log files said that it was a permissions error on C:\Windows\Installer.
- Checked C:\Windows\Installer -- sure enough, it's marked as read-only.
- I un-checked "Read-Only" in the folder properties and applied. It appears to open the dialog and apply to all files.
- However, when clicking properties again, the read-only box is backed to checked.
- Checked the security tab of the folder -- both system and the Administrators group have full access.
- I checked ownership -- the Administrators group is listed as an owner.
- Verified that I'm in the system as an Administrator (in fact, the only account in the Administrators group besides Administrator).

So, what gives? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: @Christopher -- thanks, but the issue resolved itself after taking ownership of the files twice and changing the attributes twice. who knows why it took two times, but it worked. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved by taking ownership of directories in question twice, and changing the attributes twice. Not sure that this is the correct procedure, but it installed, so I'll have to go with this being the answer for now.

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attrib command. Seems to be a common problem for people that upgrade from XP to Win7 according to this: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7security/thread/be05c603-8a55-4fe6-9335-6fa125d47381/

Comment: I've been working from a fresh install of Windows 7, however. The machine started as Vista and then was upgraded to a fresh install of 7 (i.e. clean install -- no upgrade). However, using the attrib command has helped in similar situations. In this case, I believe it resolved itself.